# Принять на вход строки и сформировать DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

на вход подается число n - это кол-во строк с данными для построения таблицы

далее на вход подаются n строк вида:
`column_name_1 data_1 ... data_n`

Кол-во строк может меняться, подскажите пожалуйста как с учетом этого принять строки и сформировать датаframe? (Наверное с помощью цикла, но у меня не получается правильно алгоритм прописать)

пробовал так, выдает ошибку

```
import pandas as pd
n = int(input()) 
for _ in range(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(input())
```

Comment: а как получается неправильно?

Comment: Добрый день!
Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
n = int(input())           # читаем кол-во
d = {}
for _ in range(n):         # читаем строки
    temp = input().split()
    d[temp.pop(0)] = temp  # и складываем в словарь
df = pd.DataFrame(d)       # делаем фрайм из словаря
print(df)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

судя по тому что на входе у вас *column_name* - это колонки дата фрейма. если это так, то собираем дата фрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(n):
    col, *val = input().split()
    df[col] = val
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте io.StringIO(string)with string в качестве строки данных для получения StringIOобъекта. Чтобы создать DataFrame, используйте pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=delimiter)with filepath_or_bufferв качестве предыдущего результата и sepназначьте его символу, разделяющему каждую запись строки в string.

```
    data_string = """Letters, Numbers
                 a, 1
                 b, 2
                 c, 3"""

data = io.StringIO(data_string)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
#создать DataFrame из `данных`


print(df)
```